# Limit of integral of multivariat continuous function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2} $ be some open set and $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$ a
> continuous function. Show that for any $\mathbf{p} \in U$ and a rectangle $R_{h}
> = \mathbf{p} + [-h, h]^{2}\subseteq U$ we have
> \begin{align*}
>   \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{4h^{2}}\int_{R_{h}}^{}\left| f( \mathbf{x})
>   - f( \mathbf{p})\right | \mathrm{~d}\mathbf{x} = 0
> .\end{align*}

We have
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{4h^{2}}\int_{R_{h}}^{}\left| f( \mathbf{x})
  - f( \mathbf{p})\right | \mathrm{~d}\mathbf{x} 
  &= 
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{4h^{2}}\int_{[-h, h]^{2}}^{}  \left| f( \mathbf{\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{h}})
  - f( \mathbf{p})\right | \mathrm{~d}\mathbf{h} 
  \\[5pt] 
  &=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{4h^{2}}\int_{-h}^{h }\int_{-h}^{h}   \left| f( \mathbf{\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{h}})
  - f( \mathbf{p})\right | \mathrm{~d}h _{1} \mathrm{~d}h _{2}
\end{align*}
with $\mathbf{h} =\begin{bmatrix}
  h_{1}  & h_{2}
\end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}} $.

I know that I somehow have to exploit continuity at this point but don't really see how I can proceed.

Comment: Mean value theorem and intermediate value theorem are your best friends

Comment: @NinadMunshi is my answer ok?

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{4h^{2}}\int_{R_{h}}^{}\left| f( \mathbf{x})
  - f( \mathbf{p})\right | \mathrm{~d}\mathbf{x} 
  &= 
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{4h^{2}}\int_{[-h, h]^{2}}^{}  \left| f( \mathbf{\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{h}})
  - f( \mathbf{p})\right | \mathrm{~d}\mathbf{h} 
  \\[5pt] 
  &=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{4h^{2}}\int_{-h}^{h }\int_{-h}^{h}   \left| f( \mathbf{\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{h}})
  - f( \mathbf{p})\right | \mathrm{~d}h _{1} \mathrm{~d}h _{2}
\end{align*}
with $\mathbf{h} =\begin{bmatrix}
  h_{1}  & h_{2}
\end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}} $.

Using the mean value theorem for integrals we can find some $a \in [-h, h]$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
\int_{-h}^{h} |f( \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{h})- f( \mathbf{p})| \mathrm{~d}h _{1}
=2h |f(p _{1} + a, p _{2} + h_{2}) - f( \mathbf{p})| 
.\end{align*}
Similarily we can find some $b \in [-h, h]$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
2h\int_{-h}^{h} \left| f( p _{1} + a, p _{2} + h _{2}) - f( \mathbf{p}) \right | \mathrm{~d}h _{2}
= 4h^{2} \left| f( p _{1} + a, p _{2} + b) - f( \mathbf{p}) \right | 
.\end{align*}
The $4h^{2}$ in the numerator and denominator of the limit cancel out and using continuity of
$f$ once again we find
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0} \left| f( p _{1} + a, p _{2} + b) - f( \mathbf{p}) \right | 
= 0
.\end{align*}